# Disable edit on separate rows in SwitUI List EditMode

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm trying to find a way to limit how many items in a list that is selectable (with EditMode), lets say I have a List with 6 items and I want the user to be able to select 3 of them, when 3 are selected I want to disable the ones that are not selected. However, I want the items that are selected to continue to be de-selectable so the other items can be selected instead.
The selectedItems Set is later converted to a data model and saved to database.

```
struct SelectItemListView: View {

var items = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"]
var numberOfselectedItems = 3 // <- controlled by user input in real project
@State var selectedItems = Set<String>()

var body: some View {
    List(items, id: \.self, selection: $selectedItems) { item in // <- id is \.id from datamodel in real project
        Text(item)
    }
    .disabled(selectedItems.count >= numberOfselectedItems)

    .environment(\.editMode, .constant(EditMode.active))
}
}
```

The code compiles but it disables the whole list, not the individual rows. Is that even possible in SwiftUI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately as of now there is no way to do what you want out of the box as far as I know.

However, it is doable by creating a custom `ListItemRow` that would take any content (a generic content basically) but it will take care of selecting and deselecting the row.

```
struct CustomListRow<Content> : View where Content : View {
    @Binding var isSelectable: Bool
    @State private var isSelected: Bool = false
    
    var onSelectionChanged :(_ isSelected:Bool) -> () = {_ in}
    
    var content: () -> Content
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Circle()
                .overlay(
                    Circle()
                        .stroke(self.isSelected ? Color.blue : Color(red: 0.741, green: 0.741, blue: 0.749), lineWidth: 1)
                        .overlay(Image(systemName: "checkmark").resizable().scaledToFit().frame(width: 12, height: 12).foregroundColor(Color.white))
            )
                .frame(width: 20, height: 20, alignment: .center)
                .foregroundColor(self.isSelected ? Color.blue : Color.clear)
            
            self.content()
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            if(self.isSelectable) {
                self.isSelected.toggle()
                self.onSelectionChanged(self.isSelected)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func onSelectionChanged(callback: @escaping (_ isSelected: Bool) -> ()) -> some View {
        CustomListRow(isSelectable: self.$isSelectable, onSelectionChanged: callback, content: self.content)
    }
}
```

and this is how to use it

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var items = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"]
    var numberOfselectedItems = 3 // <- controlled by user input in real project
    @State var selectedItems = Set<String>()
    
    var body: some View {
        List(items, id: \.self) { item in // <- id is \.id from datamodel in real project
            CustomListRow(isSelectable: Binding(get: {
                return (self.itemExist(item: item) || self.selectedItems.count < self.numberOfselectedItems)
            }, set: { _ in})) {
                Text("item: \(item) - Exist: \(self.itemExist(item: item) ? "true" : "false") - count: \(self.selectedItems.count)")
            }
            .onSelectionChanged { isSelected in
                if(isSelected == true) {
                    self.selectedItems.insert(item)
                } else {
                    self.selectedItems.remove(item)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func itemExist(item: String) -> Bool{
        return self.selectedItems.contains(item)
    }
}
```

You can take this even further and create a custom `List` that would make use of this `CustomListItemRow` and you would pass couple extra variables in the initializer such as `Data` and `MaxSelectionSize` and take care of controlling selection in the custom view to make this a reusable `List` in different projects. But this is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Amazing work! Worked like a charm right out of the box. Thank you sooo much!

Comment: Glad I was able to help. Consider marking the answer so it’s easier for others to find it.

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 17 you have the ability to control this using `selectionDisabled` method on the view for the `List` item. This way you have more granular control over which items can be selected. Be aware that the selection indicator (circle with the checkmark icon) is also not visible when passing `true`.

```swift
var body: some View {
    List(selection: $selection) {
        ForEach(items) { item in
            ItemView(item: item)
                // Only available from iOS 17
                .selectionDisabled(item.id == items.first.id)
        }
    }
}
```

See docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/selectiondisabled(_:)?changes=l__3_5